# Determining when a completed workflow instance has been persisted

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I am currently using a WorkFlowServiceHost in conjunction with the out-of-the-box SqlWorkflowInstanceStore for persistence purposes.
I need to know when a completed workflow instance has actually been persisted in the database i.e I require notification immediately after the relevant row in the [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].InstancesTable has been updated with iscompleted = 1

I have inherited from the trackingparticipant class, and overridden the TRACK method.

I then do the following to add a profile..

```
    Dim instanceQuery As New WorkflowInstanceQuery
    instanceQuery.States.Add(WorkflowInstanceStates.Completed)

    Dim runCompletedTrackingProfile As New TrackingProfile
    runCompletedTrackingProfile.Name = "runCompletedTrackingProfile"
    runCompletedTrackingProfile.Queries.Add(instanceQuery)

    Dim trackingParticipant As New RunCompletedTrackingParticipant With {.TrackingProfile = runCompletedTrackingProfile}

    _CommPayRunWorkFlowServiceHost.WorkflowExtensions.Add(trackingParticipant)
```

This all works fine, and if I put a breakpoint in my TrackingParticipant class it will be hit at the expected time.
HOWEVER, at this point, although the workflow instance in memory is COMPLETED, the database has not yet been updated.
I assume that this is because the persistence code is running on the same thread, because if I start another thread within my trackingparticipant,
I can see that the 'iscompleted' field DOES get updated.

What is the most elegant way of achieving this without continually polling the database ?  I've looked at the .WaitForEvents method on the instance store, but this does not appear to do what I need

Answer (score 1):

Because the I/O is done async any design that calls for you to do this is likely to to produce fragile code.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Ron is 100% right here -- nevermind the fact that he runs the WF program :) -- anything you're persisting to, which is probably MSSQL Server in your case I'm guessing, is going to throw errors if it doesn't get persisted. However, if you require notification surrounding persistence OR completion build a custom activity that sends that notification when those things occur. That should be pretty straight forward. If you need some help let us know but we'll need a bit more information surrounding your requirement.

Comment: Please see the following for the context of what I'm tring to achive: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar-SA/wfprerelease/thread/8cd8a42c-17dd-43e3-a405-367feb4d75cd

Comment: In particular, see my comment about needing to close my workflowservicehost, reconfigure it with a new guid for correlation purposes, and then re-open it following completion of the instance. As part of this process I need to query the instance store. Just to reiterate, it's the actual persistence itself I'm interested in, not simply knowing that the instance in MEMORY is complete

Comment: As far as I'm aware, having a custom activity won't actually cut it, because if the activity is part of the workflow, then the workflow won't yet be persisted in the Complete state.

Comment: Otherwise I can end up with a situation where I query the instance store, finding an instance where iscompleted = 0 even though the instance n memory is complete, simply because the persistence mechanism hasn't quite caught up. A race condition in other words

Comment: As you can tell, workflow doesn't like singletons.  Nothing about it was designed to really support the scenario from the ground up.  WCF on the other hand easily supports singletons.  Would it be possible to rethink your design to use WCF for the messaging?  Or better yet, perhaps you should think about building your system without a singleton.

Comment: oops. What I actually need is a WorkflowApplicationServiceHost, which doesn't exist ! :-) 
The existing WorkflowApplication class provides a host for a single instance of a workflow but it doesn't have the tight integration with WCF which I need. I could add it but it would be quite a lot of extra work I think, as opposed to the WorkflowServiceHost which does a lot of stuff for you in terms of generating service contracts and exposing end points etc.

Comment: Unfortunately my process does need to be a singleton - I have a complex set of stored procs as part of a financial process, and it would wreak havoc if I had more than one instance at the same time. My primary reasons for using workflow are the built in persistence, in particular the ability to reload and resume an aborted instance following a crash/power failure or whatever.